# How to dump user's environment into a file?

Tags: 12.04, bash, log

I want to dump all user's environment into 'env.log'.
Please tell me the command to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`env` prints the environments. To save it into a file use output redirection:

```
env > env.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As the user you can do:

```
env > env.log
```

A file called `env.log` will be written in the current directory. If you want it somewhere else, you can use the path like this: `env > /var/log/userenv.log`. A double ">" will append to the file instead of overwriting. If the file does not exist, it will be created in any case as long as you have write access to the location.

Comment: @mahnoorfatima: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

`printenv > env.txt` will create a file with all the environment variable name and value pairs.